# Communication between an application in play activator and server in amazon aws

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, typesafe-activator

I have been studying several blogs but I couldn't get a clear picture.I am building a web application which uses Scala actors for concurrency.My basic goal is to concurrently update a shared file in the server.And I am planning to use AWS for it. I see in several blogs people talking about deploying play application in AWS.Does it mean I install the whole activator for play v2.3.5 in AWS or just place my application.If its placing my application how can I actually modify it and test it with activator. Can any one give a clear picture of process to follow to build my application?. These are the blogs I researched. They may be understandable but I couldn't get a clear picture being naive.

http://rijware.com/play-application-amazon-ec2-instance/
https://aishwaryasinghal.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/deploy-play-2-application-on-aws-with-tomcat-and-apache-httpd/ and few more..

Comment: Did you read this? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production

Comment: By this I understood that I need to install play on AwS to run my application with start. Am I right? If yes how to install play frame work on Amazon AWS. I only find tutorials to deploy applications in it.

Comment: You don't really "install" Play on AWS. Rather, you create a distributable binary of your Play-based app using the `dist` command as documented at the URL that @Ryan referenced.  You now have a single file you can execute in any server.  So, for AWS, create your server, get the binary that you created on it, and then execute the binary with `./my-app-name`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that "may" help you understand Play and how it can be deployed on EC2.

- Play is *containerless* web framework - i.e., you don't need to deploy your Play application to a container (like you do with traditional container based web frameworks such JBoss and Tomcat). Instead you use it as a library and it gets bundled into a jar file. All you need to run this jar is a JVM. So if you have a EC2 VM that has a modern JVM you can just invoke the jar file.
- Typesafe activator is a nice little tool that helps you create Play and other reactive apps by creating a project directory structure, generating your build.sbt, adding necessary plugins, showing the output on the on the browser etc. But it is essentially a *wrapper over sbt* (http://www.scala-sbt.org).
  So you don't need to install activator to run your Play app.
- Here is one way to deploy your Play app on EC2.

  1. Create your project on your local machine using activator.
  2. Build and test this app locally
  3. Create a distribution using `activator dist` or `sbt dist`. This should create a zip file for you with all the necessary dependencies.
  4. `scp` this file to your EC2 VM
  5. Unzip the file to a dir (`$MY_APP`)
  6. Run the app by using the script (`$MY_APP/bin/<my-app-name>`)

You can actually follow the exact same steps on the remote EC2 VM if you have your project there. You either install activator or sbt on the remote VM.